# Dominating frequencies time series

Tags: matlab, fft

I have a time series data. I performed fft on it using matlab as:

```
ft=fft(data);
```

How do we get the dominating frequencies. I tried taking the maximum value of ft, but it appears to be wrong. How can we get dominating frequencies

Comment: Sampling rate of your data will be needed to find dominating frequencies.

Comment: Sampling rate of my data is 1

Comment: You mean your data's sampling frequency is 1Hz?

Comment: My time series is sampled, such that I have one value at every time step.

Comment: I need your time step period. It means the time between first sample and second sample.

Comment: I had a time series such as at every second, there were some values, as the values were same for many subsequent seconds, I averaged for consecutive 10 seconds. Now the time series data is like at second 1 it has value averaged from 1-10 initial seconds and second 2 is 11-20 initial seconds and so on

Comment: In what frequency range are you expecting a dominating frequency?

Answer (score 1):

You need to take the *magnitude* of the complex FFT output and find the peaks:

```
ft=fft(data);
mag_ft = abs(ft);    % take magnitude of FFT complex output values
```

Comment: In my code, I need to compute 1/dominating frequency. Using above code, I get max frequency as 1783.4, making 1/1783.4 very small. Is it ok, if I normalize fft as ft=fft(data)/length(data)? Does it hamper the result, in negative way

Comment: If you just want to find the *frequency* of the largest peak then it makes no difference whether you normalise the magnitude or not, since you are just scaling all the magnitudes by the same constant value. The peaks will still be at the same frequencies.

Answer (score 0):

First, frequency axis will be needed to find frequencies of your fft data. Since your sampling rate is just 1, maximum frequency you can check will be 0.5 Hz.

```
dt=1; % your time step

N=length(data);  % data length

df=1/(dt*N);  %frequency bin

f_axis=(0:N-1)*df; % frequency axis
```

And then, plot your fft data with the frequency axis.

```
ft=fft(data);
plot(f_axis,abs(ft));
```